# Importing packages from GitHub in pubspec yaml, requires pubspec.yaml file which isnt in the repository

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have issues using `flutter pub get` with a repository package in my pubspec.yaml file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_stripe:
    git: 
      url: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe.git
      ref: poc-use-expensive-androidview
```

Following the steps provided https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages.

However, I am getting the error

```
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe.git 7934151fefed73c6a22c253de3a1f1c9d46decc2.
pub get failed (1; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe.git 7934151fefed73c6a22c253de3a1f1c9d46decc2.)
```

I have no idea what I am suppose to put for the pubspec.yaml which is not present in the repository. And it works fine if you call the package as it is using `flutter pub add flutter_stripe`.

The reason I am required to use an unofficial branch is because one of the fields provided by the package is not working correctly, and the suggested solution is to use this branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the packages of the git project you can see more then one package: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/packages
You have to choose the package(s) you need.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, my bad, I didnt know that the root of the Hosted package isn't the final path. I was required to add a path to the packages, which can then be found in ./packages/stripe.

```
flutter_stripe:
    git: 
      url: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe.git
      ref: poc-use-expensive-androidview
      path: ./packages/stripe
```

For anyone who has the same issue as me... or maybe i'm just noob

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).